# Error maxClauseCount searching if certain property is null or not null

Tags: lucene, alfresco

When I try to search with Lucene in Alfresco if certain property is not null:

```
myProperty IS NOT NULL;
```

or is null:

```
myProperty IS NULL;
```

I have this error:

> *org.apache.lucene.search.BooleanQuery$TooManyClauses - maxClauseCount is set to 10000*

This is my query:

```
 SELECT D.cmis:name, D.cmis:objectId, D.cmis:creationDate, R.regxun:numReg, R.regxun:numInterno FROM cmis:document AS D JOIN regxun:contextoRegistroBase AS R ON D.cmis:objectId = R.cmis:objectId WHERE D.cmis:creationDate >= TIMESTAMP '2016-02-18T00:00:00.000Z' AND D.cmis:creationDate < TIMESTAMP '2016-02-19T00:00:00.000Z' AND R.regxun:ambitoDoc='prrubuh' AND R.regxun:numReg IS NOT NULL
```

Any alternative?

Comment: Is this your whole query?

Comment: @DisplayName This is my query: SELECT D.cmis:name, D.cmis:objectId, D.cmis:creationDate, R.regxun:numReg, R.regxun:numInterno FROM cmis:document AS D JOIN regxun:contextoRegistroBase AS R ON D.cmis:objectId = R.cmis:objectId WHERE D.cmis:creationDate >= TIMESTAMP '2016-02-18T00:00:00.000Z' AND D.cmis:creationDate < TIMESTAMP '2016-02-19T00:00:00.000Z' AND R.regxun:ambitoDoc='prrubuh' AND R.regxun:numRegl IS NOT NULL

Comment: Please [edit] your question and put your query there. Code in comments is very hard to read.

Comment: That is SQL, not a Lucene query. How can this query give the error from your question?

Comment: This is a Alfresco search with cmis, and cmis use lucene. This problem happens when you have a lot of documents. I'm trying to check if certain property has value or not.

Answer (score 0):

Increase the **lucene.query.maxClauses** in the alfresco-global.properties to a higher number than 10000.

Like:

```
lucene.query.maxClauses=100000
```

But I wouldn't keep it that high, just try to leave the **IS NOT NULL** statement, which creates a lot of OR clauses in the database query.

For example what you could do is create a rule or behaviour which fill the custom property with a special value (like 'empty') and then search on that.

Comment: Increase maxClauses not is an option for me. I can't change this in Alfresco and I  can't fill the property. I can only make queries. I've tried change  myProperty IS NOT NULL for myProperty LIKE '%' , but I have the same problem.

Comment: If that is not an option and you can't fill in the property, then you can't get this fixed :). You could use the javascript-console where you can recurisive run through the whole repo and fill in the property.